# Not adding to database

Tags: php, mysql

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. Every time it throws up an error:

```
$GROUPCREATE = $_POST['GROUPCREATE'];
$USER = $_POST['USER'];
mysql_connect ("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXX") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("XXXX");
$query="INSERT INTO contacts_groups (id, GROUP, USER)VALUES ('NULL','".$GROUPCREATE."','".$USER."')";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());
header( 'Location: add_done.php' ) ;
```

I get the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP, USER)VALUES ('NULL','Group Name','Username')' at line 1

I can't figure it out! The code looks all right and is pretty much identical to one I have used on another (fully working) form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP` is a protected keyword in MySQL, which means if you absolutely *have* to use it as a field identifier, you will have to put it in backticks like this

```
`GROUP`
```

The better version would be to just avoid protected keywords. You can get a list of them all at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP` is a reserved word in mysql. You'll have to "escape" it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO contacts_groups (id, `GROUP`, USER) ...
```

Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection, so better take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Because GROUP is reserved word in MySQL (GROUP BY). You should change the name of your field of add quotes like it ` .

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP` is a MySQL reserved keyword so it is breaking your query. You need to escape it with back ticks like so:

```
`GROUP`
```

See the [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) manual page.

So your code should be something like:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `contacts_groups` (`id`, `GROUP`, `USER`)
        VALUES ('NULL','$GROUPCREATE','$USER')";
```

You will also noticed that I have removed the unnecessary string concatenation you had in your query.

You should also be careful what you are putting into your SQL queries to prevent SQL injection occurring. As a bare minimum you should be running the following before your query:

```
$GROUPCREATE = mysql_real_escape_string($GROUPCREATE);
```

On all the PHP variables you are going to drop into your query.

Ideally you would be using [PHPs PDO classes](http://php.net/pdo) and using place holders so that your data/variables is/are automatically escaped.